# Allow multiple local servers to share a local domain

Tags: linux, networking, dns, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm wanting to set up multiple local servers in VMWare. For example, one web server, one file server, one openvpn server, etc.

I would like to create a domain that works locally (e.g. *example.localservers*) which points to the web server that they could all access. However, I would also like to share that domain with the other servers (e.g. *files.example.localservers, vpn.example.localservers*) so that everything is separated and they are all on different local IP's.

How could I approach this?

Comment: Are you already running a DNS server? (If so, which?)

Comment: No, I'm not running any kind of dedicated DNS server. Imagine the setup purely as 3 seperate VMWare CentOS instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick, 10,000ft view of how a DNS server works (at least w/r/t your question):

1. A DNS server is an ordinary daemon on a ordinary host. It listens on TCP and UDP port 53 for queries. For our purposes, the only query is *what is the IP address of `foo.example.com`?* (or whatever hostname).
2. The DNS a few possible answers for that query:

   1. There is no such host name.
   2. I have no clue. (This is an error condition.)
   3. The IP address is 10.11.12.13 (or whatever).
   4. Ask the DNS server/nameserver at (some host name).
3. The fourth answer, above, is how DNS delegation works. There are a bunch of root servers. Those tell you to ask the nameservers for `com`. Then those servers tell you to ask the nameserver for `example.com`, etc.
4. A DNS server has two sources of knowledge: local configuration and talking to other DNS servers (note: for efficiency, knowledge gained from other servers is cached). Local configuration includes the list of root nameservers (or at least a few of them; you can ask any of them for the full list), the list of zones this server handles, and the host→IP mapping for those zones.
5. A zone is just an area of control in DNS. Typically, one or more of the dot-separated parts. In `foo.example.com`, there is the root zone, a `com` zone, and an `example.com` zone. If there is an `a.foo.example.com`, sometimes that will be part of the `example.com` zone, sometimes there will be an additional `foo.example.com` zone—it's a configuration decision of the `example.com` admins.
6. A DNS server handles two different types of queries: recursive and non-recursive. Recursive queries mainly come from random computers (clients). Non-recursive queries mainly come from other DNS servers. A recursive query asks the DNS server to fully resolve a name, handling that "ask that other server" itself. A non-recursive query just returns where to ask instead.

If you have 3 hosts, don't know DNS, and aren't itching to learn it, stevieb's suggestion of using a hosts file is fine. Every time you add a host, you'll have to add it to the hosts file on *all* hosts, but if it's only a few hosts, that's not such a big deal.

OTOH, if you'd like to set up DNS, you're going to have to spend some time reading about it—I personally learned a lot from an earlier edition of [DNS and BIND](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100574) but it's been a while and there may be better sources now. In short, you'll configuring a local caching nameserver, make it authoritative for `example.localservers`, and then give it all your host→IP mappings. (And IP→host mappings as well, and possibly other stuff too).

Finally, if you're using a registered, globally-recognized domain (one you picked up at Namecheap, etc.) you might find it easier to just add the name→IP mappings to their DNS service, which you can probably do using a control panel on their site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running a DNS server, add the entries to the `/etc/hosts` file on all of the machines in question:

```
echo "
10.0.1.1 files.example.local
10.0.0.4 vpn.example.local
10.0.0.4 www.example.local
" | sudo tee --append /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Would an easier way to be to set up another server purely as a DNS server and just assign those addresses to that server, and point the other servers towards it?

Comment: I would set up a proper DNS server for internal use with just this one domain, and then set it to forward other requests to your ISP's DNS recursive server. It's not easier initially, but in the long run it's much more maintainable.

Comment: @Jack the way you're asking about assigning addresses to a DNS server makes me think you'd first need to learn how DNS works... A DNS server just converts names to numbers. It doesn't have addresses (other than its own IP address, e.g., the one you put in resolv.conf) assigned to it...